# Настройка ActiveMQ Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq

Как настроить в пропертях такое поведение очереди:

Необходимо добавить минимальное время ожидания, максимальное время ожидания и сам множитель, для наращивания интервала.

Пример, прочитали сообщение из очереди, если по ходу дальнейшей логики у нас ошибка, то читаем снова через 4 секунды, потом если снова неудача, то через 8 секунд, потом через 16 секунд и так до верхнего предела.

```
activemq:
  brokerUrl: url
  user: user
  password: password
  requestTimeout: 30000
  maxConnections: 5
  send-timeout: 1s
  close-timeout: 15s
  non-blocking-redelivery: true
```

это вроде все проверти что я нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вот это [Quartz Job Scheduling](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)